# Зарезервировать место в сегменте данных для массива

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Ассемблер вообще не понятен, и не ясно, как выполнить последующие задачи для FASM, TASM - как угодно. Очень нужно разобраться в этом.

1. Зарезервировать место в памяти в сегменте данных Dseg_1 для массива байт в 10 элементов MasB.
2. Зарезервировать место в памяти во втором сегменте данных Dseg_2 для массива слов в 30 элементов с именем MasW.

Можно даже дать материал для изучения и разбора последующих задач:

3. Зарезервировать место в дополнительном сегменте Eseg для таблицы, состоящей из 10-ти записей по 4 элемента TablB.
4. Зарезервировать место в дополнительном сегменте Eseg для таблицы двойных слов с именем TablAdr 40 элементов.
5. Используя прямую адресацию с индексированием заполнить массив MasB.
6. Используя базовую адресацию со смещением заполнить MasW.
7. Используя базовую адресацию с индексированием заполнить TablB следующим образом: в виде содержания 1-го элемента каждой записи берётся элемент MasB с тем же номером, что и номер записи. В виде содержания остальных полей берётся первый байт элементов MasW по порядку их следования в массиве.
8. Используя попеременно, если это возможно или команду загрузки абсолютного адреса, или псевдооператоры SEG, OFFSET заполнить таблицу TablAdr так, чтобы каждый элемент таблицы указывал собой адрес соответствующего элемента таблицы TablB.
9. Используя операции со стеком сначала оставляем в TablB порядок элементов в записях неизменными, изменить в обратном порядке расположение записей, а потом не изменяя расположения записей изменить на обратный порядок элементы.

Для меня тут практически ничего не ясно, но задания нужно сделать. Буду очень благодарна, если подскажите, в какую сторону двигаться. В смысле где найти материал, соответствующий данным заданиям. Или попробовать решить, но не знаю - слишком массивно.

**UPD: РЕЗУЛЬТАТ**

В итоге всё дошло до такого кода:

```
sseg        segment para stack 'stack'
    db      256 dup(?)
sseg        ends

; 1 Зарезервувати місце в пам’яті у сегменті даних Dseg_1 для масиву байт у 10 елементів MasB.
Dseg_1  segment para public 'data'
    MasB        db 10 dup ('0')
Dseg_1  ends

; 2 Зарезервувати місце у пам’яті у другому сегменті даних Dseg_2 для масиву слів у 30 елементів з ім’ям MasW.
Dseg_2   segment para public 'data'
    MasW    dw 30 dup ('f')
Dseg_2  ends

; 3 Зарезервувати місце у додатковому сегменті Eseg для таблиці, складеної з 10 записів по 4 елемента TablB.
Eseg        segment para public 'data'
    TablB       db 10 dup (4 dup (0))
    ; 4 Зарезервувати місце у додатковому сегменті Eseg для таблиці подвійних слів з ім’ям TablAdr 40 елементів.
    TablAdr dd 40 dup (0)
Eseg        ends

cseg        segment para public 'code'
assume  cs:cseg, ds:Dseg_1, ss:sseg, es:Eseg
start       proc far
    ;
    push        ds
    sub     ax, ax
    push        ax
    ;
    mov     bx, Dseg_1
    mov         ds, bx
    ;
    call        main
    ret
start       endp

main        proc near
    ;инициализация таблицы TablB и TablAdr
    mov     bx, Eseg
    mov     es, bx

    ;5 Використовуючи пряму адресацію з індексуванням заповнити масив MasB.
    mov     byte ptr ds:[0], 'a'
    mov     byte ptr ds:[1], 'b'
    mov     byte ptr ds:[2], 'c'
    mov     byte ptr ds:[3], 'd'
    mov     byte ptr ds:[4], 'e'
    mov     byte ptr ds:[5], 'f'
    mov     byte ptr ds:[6], 'g'
    mov     byte ptr ds:[7], 'h'
    mov     byte ptr ds:[8], 'i'
    mov     byte ptr ds:[9], 'j'

    ;6 переход к Dseg_2
    assume  ds: Dseg_2
    mov         bx, Dseg_2
    mov     ds, bx

    ; 6 Використовуючи базову адресацію зі зміщенням заповнити MasW.
    lea     dx, MasW            ;в dx заносится адрес масива
    mov     cx, 30d             ;количество итераций
    mov     bx, 0d              ;начальное смещение
    mov     ax, 1h
m2:             
    mov     [MasW+bx], ax   ;
    inc     ax
    inc     bx              ;
    inc     bx              ;работаем со словом, поэтому увелчиваем bx на 2
    dec     cx              ;тело цикла заполнения
    jnz     m2              ;
    ret
main        endp
cseg        ends
end start
```

Который есть на просторах Интернета + незначительные изменения с убором метки, которая Тасмом не воспринималась. Тасм выдаёт "Passes: 1", остальных ошибок вроде нет, но и работать программа не хочет. В любом случае, разобраться стоило. Более-менее понятно.

Comment: Если программа ничего не выводит, то не факт, что она не работает, в данном случае у нее никакого вывода нет. По задумке, видимо, предполагалось, что под отладчиком ее нужно будет запускать и смотреть что она делает.

Comment: Кстати, `mov byte ptr ds:[0], 'a'` - это явно не адресация с индексированием, а просто прямая абсолютная. Индексная адресация предполагает использование, собственно, индексного регистра (`si` или `di`, вроде бы `bx` тоже может выступать индексным регистром ЕМНИП) для выбора конкретного элемента массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Зарезервировать место в памяти

Тут все просто: объявляется сегмент, объявляется переменная, указывается размер (`db`, `dw`, `dd` и т.д.), указывается сколько элементов нужно выделить при помощи директивы `dup`. По сути операция эквивалентна объявлению глобально доступного массива на языках высокого уровня.

Пример (синтаксис fasm)

```
segment Dseg_1 ; Начало сегмента

MasB db 10 dup (?) ; Вопрос означает, что данные не инициализированы (т.е. по факту там может оказаться все что угодно)
; Если нужно заполнить массив, например, числами 10 - пишем 10 вместо вопросительного знака
MasB2 rb 10 ; Альтернативный вариант, будет работать только в fasm - буквально означает "зарезервировать байты" (reserve bytes)
; по смыслу делает то же что и предыдущий вариант

segment Dseg_2

MasW dw 30 dup (?) ; или
MasW2 rw 30
```

3 и 4 пункт аналогично. Для 3 пункта выделяем просто 10*4 = 40 элементов.

```
segment Eseg

TablB db 10*4 dup (?) ; или TablB rb 10*4
TablAdr dd 40 dup (?) ; или TablAdr rd 40
```

Я предпочитаю использовать вариант `rb`/`rw`/`rd`, т.к. постоянно забываю что должно быть слева, а что справа от `dup`.

### 2. Заполнение массивов с использованием различных режимов адресации

Тут все немного сложнее, для ознакомления почитайте, например, на [fasmworld.ru](https://fasmworld.ru/):

- [Режимы адресации](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/014-rezhimy-adresacii/)
- [Циклы и команда LOOP](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/013-cikly-i-komanda-loop/)
- ну и [Сегментная адресация](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/031-segmentnaya-adresaciya/)

Для примера покажу п.5:

```
...
; Помещаем адрес сегмента в сегментный регистр (в два этапа, напрямую в ds его положить нельзя)
mov ax, Dseg_1
mov ds, ax
mov cx, 10 ; будем заполнять 10 байт
mov di, 0 ; устанавливаем индекс (номер элемента массива) на 0
init_loop1:
mov [MasB+di], 0 ; записываем по адресу MasB+di ноль (можно любое другое число)
inc di ; увеличиваем di на 1 (переходим к следующему элементу)
loop init_loop1 ; делаем цикл: уменьшаем cx на 1, сравниваем с 0, если больше - то переходим по указанной метке
```

Это, конечно, не вся программа, а только цикл, выполняющий требуемые действия.

Далее все еще хитрее, но в принципе решаемо. Советую ознакомиться с [курсом по ассемблеру на fasmworld.ru](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnik/), для начала хотя бы поверхностно, возможно что-то станет понятнее. Курс ориентирован на использование ассемблера fasm.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за уделённое внимание! Пойду разберусь со всем этим. Ситуация стала значительно яснее, спасибо с:

Answer (score 0):

лет двадцать не держал в руках ассемблер.

Вот, что нашлось про TASM и сегменты данных
 http://www.codenet.ru/progr/asm/tasm/26.php
http://volgota.com/yaroslavz/assembler-6-segmenty

В вашем случае наверное как-то так(1,2)

```
Dseg_1 SEGMENT BYTE 
DB     10
Dseg_1 ENDS
Dseg_2 SEGMENT WORD
DW     30
Dseg_2 ENDS
```

Comment: `db 10` как и `db 30` просто резервируют по одному байту с соответствующим значением. `SEGMENT BYTE` тоже по-моему не бывает, `WORD` в данном случае скорее всего означает текстовое название сегментов (возможно, для отладки).

Comment: Поправил, конечно же DW. Просто с обеда вопрос висит без комментов, надо ж было кому то начать - стряхнул пыль с извилин :)

Comment: И все равно так получатся не массивы, а безымянные переменные из 1 и 2 байт соответственно первая и вторая. Я это вопрос днем мельком увидел, но только сейчас дошли руки ответить.